# ggplot: Boxplot by several categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, yaxis, cowplot

I am trying to plot several boxplots in one chart using ggplot2. I have 1 continuous variable and several factors. I would like to have a single Y axis and each pair of boxplots to have their own x axis with their own factor levels. So far, I tried to use **`cowplot::plot_grid`** to join together charts that I made separately with an empty chart that I use for the Y axis. I tried to make the charts blend nicely by hiding margins and resizing the charts but I still cannot get reasonable results and this method involves too much manual tweaking.
This is what I want to get and what I came up so far:
[charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFhRP.png)

And this is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(dplyr)

# make a dataset:
DF <- mtcars
DF$cyl <- as.factor(DF$cyl)
DF$vs <- as.factor(DF$vs)
DF$am <- as.factor(DF$am)
DF$gear <- as.factor(DF$gear)
DF$carb <- as.factor(DF$carb)
#str(DF)

# fisrt boxplot
p1 <- DF %>% ggplot() + theme_grey() + aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=cyl) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t=0.1, r=0, b=0, l=0, unit="cm"))

# second boxplot
p2 <- DF %>% ggplot() + theme_grey() + aes(x=vs, y=mpg, fill=vs) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t=0.1, r=0, b=0, l=0, unit="cm"))

# empty boxplot used only for the y axis
y_axis <- DF %>% ggplot() + theme_grey() + aes(x=mpg, y=mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(),
        axis.text.x = element_text()) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t=0.1, r=0, b=0, l=0, unit="cm"))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0), breaks=c(0), labels = c(""), name="")

# join all charts toghether
p_all <- plot_grid(y_axis, p1, p2,
                   align="v", axis="l", 
                   nrow=1, rel_widths = c(0.2, 1, 1))

ggdraw(p_all)
```

Comment: what u r expecting on x axis and on y axis? generally it can be done in ggplot with `gacet_grid / facet_wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
x <- DF
x$cars <- rownames(x)
x <- melt(x[,c("cars", "cyl", "mpg", "vs")], id.vars=c("cars", "mpg"))

ggplot(x, aes(x=value,y=mpg))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~variable, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

I first converted your data-format with `melt()` so that faceting is possible. I suppose you can go from here and do the rest of the formatting by yourself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I put all in a function and added some customizations. Now it works just fine.

Comment: Wow, what an elegant solution! A pity, though, if one needs a real faceting on top :( I wish ggplot allowed a nested faceting

Answer (score 7):

This is how it looks like with several variables, some color and using `tidyr`. You can add the border between the plots with `panel.border` and should specify the number of rows to be 1 in the `facet_wrap`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Only select variables meaningful as factor
DF <- select(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb) 

DF %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -mpg) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(value), mpg, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is almost the same as alex_555's solution, only with tidyr::gather rather than reshape2::melt. I'll probably import tidyr for other functions as well so this may end up more useful eventually.